# What is the best way to configure iPlanet/Sun ONE be the HTTP/HTTPS front end to a JBoss/Tomcat application?

Tags: apache, tomcat, jboss, sunone

What is the best way to configure iPlanet/Sun ONE be the HTTP/HTTPS front end to a JBoss/Tomcat application?

Are there any performance considerations?

How would this compare with the native integration between Apache httpd and Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins available for iPlanet which do exactly this.  Check out the Reverse Proxy plugin in the documentation for iPlanet.

This may help:
http://docs.sun.com/source/816-7156-10/agplugin.html#18923

Comment: can any body please share the latest location of these files, as now we are getting redirected to oracle site.
thanks
satyendra

Comment: Just use wayback.archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20090129201107/http://docs.sun.com/source/816-7156-10/agplugin.html#18923, then click on the Jan 29th, 2009 date.